# Approximating the distribution for $\bar{X}/s$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

> Let $\bar{X}$ and $s^2$ be the sample mean and variance for a random sample of size $n$ from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution. Consider the statistic $T_n=\bar{X}/s$.
>
> (a) Express the standardized statistic $T^*_n=\sqrt{n}(T_n-\operatorname{plim} T_n)$ in the form $(A_n+B_n)/C_n$ where $A_n$ obeys a central limit theorem and both $B_n$ and $C_n$ converge in probability to constants.
>
> (b) Using this expression for $T^*_n$, find its limiting distribution. Convert the limiting distribution into an approximation for the distribution of $T_n$.
>
> (c) Check your result in (b) by using the delta method for calculating asymptotic variances.

I'm having some difficulties in solving this problem. Here's how I tried solving it:

(a)

$T_n \xrightarrow{p}\mu/\delta$, thus

$T^*_n=\sqrt{n}(\frac{\bar X}{s}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})$

$=\frac{1}{s}(\sqrt n(\bar X-\mu)-\sqrt n(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}s-\mu))$

$\sqrt n(\bar X-\mu) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\sqrt n(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}s-\mu)\xrightarrow{d} N(0,\frac{\mu^2}{2})$ by CLT.

$\therefore\sqrt n(\bar X-\mu)-\sqrt n(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}s-\mu) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2+\frac{\mu^2}{2})$ (because $\bar X $ and $s$ are independent)

So $T^*_n$ can be expressed as $\sqrt n((\bar X+\frac{\mu}{\sigma}s)-2\mu)$ (which obeys CLT, thus $A_n$)
over $s$ (which converges in probability to $\sigma$, thus $C_n$), but I don't see the component corresponding to $B_n$. Is it okay to just say that $B_n=0$, or did I get something wrong here?

Also, I don't understand what (b) wants me to do. by Slutsky's theorem,

$$\sqrt n\left(T_n-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\xrightarrow{d}N\left(0,1+\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

This is what I get from finding the limiting distribution of $T^*_n$, but what does it mean to "convert" this to an approximation for the distribution of $T_n$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$T^*_n=\sqrt{n}\Bigg(\frac{\overline{X}_n}{S}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{S}\Bigg(\overline{X}_n-\frac{\mu S}{\sigma}\Bigg)=\frac{\overline{X}_n-\frac{\mu S}{\sigma}}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}\rightarrow\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$$

- $A_n=\overline{X}_n$

it's the sample mean, evidently obeying CLT

- $B_n=-\mu\frac{S}{\sigma}\xrightarrow{P} -\mu$

$-B_n$ converges to the mean of the sample mean

- $C_n=\frac{ S}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{P} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

$C_n$ converges to the st dev of the sample mean

Thus

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
T^*_n \dot{\sim} N(0;1)
\
}
$$

---

Having found the limiting distribution for $T^*_n$  I think you will not have problem in converting it into an approximation for the distribution of $T_n$

This results to me

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{T_n\dot{\sim}N\Bigg[\frac{\mu}{\sigma};\frac{1}{n}\Bigg]
\
}
$$

---

Using delta method to check asymptotic variance you get

$$g[T^*_n]=\frac{T^*_n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$$

Thus

$$V[T_n]=V[T^*_n][g'(T^*_n)]^2=\frac{1}{n}$$

As calculated before

Comment: Thank you, now I get the idea. But shouldn't $T^*_n \sim N(0,1)$ since $T^*_n \xrightarrow{p} \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$ and $\bar{X} \sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$? (and accordingly, $T_n \sim N(\frac{\mu}{\sigma},\frac{1}{n})$?)

Comment: @khl : yes, of course! amended.

Comment: Just did! Can I ask you one more? In my original question, I got $\sqrt n\left(T_n-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\xrightarrow{d}N\left(0,1+\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, but now I get $N\left(0,1\right)$. What's the difference between the two solutions? Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct, and the result is the same.

$$T^*_n=\frac{1}{S}\Bigg[\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-\mu)-\sqrt{n}\Bigg(\frac{\mu S}{\sigma}-\mu\Bigg)\Bigg]$$

Now

$$\sqrt{n}\Bigg(\frac{\mu S}{\sigma}-\mu\Bigg)\xrightarrow{P}0$$

And
$$\frac{1}{S}\Bigg[\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-\mu)\Bigg]\sim\mathcal{T}_{(n-1)}\dot{\sim}N(0;1)$$

Thus using Slutsky you get

$$T^*_n\dot{\sim}N(0;1)$$